# Windows TCP Congestion Control

Tags: windows, windows-7, tcp

I noticed doing `netsh interface tcp show global` that `Add-On Congresion Control Provider` was set to `none`. What does that mean exactly? I'm guessing it means it uses windows default Congestion Control? What is the default for windows anyway?

Answer (score 2):

`netsh interface tcp>sh gl

...

congestionprovider - One of the following values:

none: Use the built-in standard congestion control algorithm.

ctcp: Use the add-on Compound TCP congestion control algorithm.

default: Restore the selected provider to the system default.

...`

The default for Windows 7 is none (you can test this by `netsh int tcp se gl cong=default`).

For Windows 2008, the default was CTCP according to this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb878127.aspx (Section entitled Compound TCP).
On my R2 TMG machine, it's set to CTCP, so it appears that the link above is correct, and that for client OSs it's off, for servers it's on.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_TCP

The short description is: If you're expecting to be running applications that have a large volume of data in Sends that may be unacknowledged at any point, CTCP may help when large-latency networks are involved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Microsoft has now set the default congestion control algorithm to [Cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUBIC_TCP) for [Windows Server 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-server/get-started-19/whats-new-19). This in line with Linux and MacOS which also currently default to Cubic.

Comment: It's too bad that cubic is really bad with any network hardware suffering from bufferbloat. Better algorithms such as CDG or Vegas would help a lot there.